# Migrating from Babel to SWC with React

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, jsx, swc-compiler

#### TL;DR

How to translate a node script like this:

```json
"test": "NODE_ENV=test riteway -r @babel/register 'src/**/*.test.js' | tap-nirvana",
```

to use [SWC](https://swc.rs/) instead of Babel?

---

#### Context

We recently upgraded our Next.js version. Next.js now supports [SWC instead of Babel.](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/upgrading/version-12#swc-replacing-babel)

The unit tests for React in our project are written with [RITEway](https://github.com/ericelliott/riteway). The test command is:

```json
"test": "NODE_ENV=test riteway -r @babel/register 'src/**/*.test.js' | tap-nirvana",
```

It transforms the files with Babel first because otherwise `import` statements and JSX would cause errors.

During our attempts to migrating to SWC, we had no luck with the CLI. However, we found the [`@swc-node/register` package](https://github.com/Brooooooklyn/swc-node/tree/master/packages/register). It allowed us to transform our command like this:

```json
"test": "riteway -r @swc-node/register src/**/*.test.js | tap-nirvana"
```

which fixes new syntax like the `import` statement and a test like this would run:

```
import { describe } from 'riteway';

describe('my test', async assert => {
  assert({
    given: 'true',
    should: 'be true',
    actual: true,
    expected: true,
  });
});
```

However, tests for React components like this

```js
import { describe } from 'riteway';
import render from 'riteway/render-component';

import Authentication from './user-authentication-component';

describe('user authentication component', async assert => {
  const $ = render(<Authentication />);

  assert({
    given: 'just rendering',
    should: "render 'Authentication'",
    actual: $('*:contains("Authentication")').text(),
    expected: 'Authentication',
  });
});
```

still throw the following error:

```
$ yarn test
yarn run v1.22.17
$ riteway -r @swc-node/register src/**/*.test.js | tap-nirvana
/Users/user/dev/learning-flow/node_modules/@swc/core/index.js:135
        return bindings.transformSync(isModule ? JSON.stringify(src) : src, isModule, toBuffer(newOptions));
                        ^

Error: error: Expression expected
 
  |
7 |   const $ = render(<Authentication />);
  |                                    ^

error: Expression expected
 
  |
7 |   const $ = render(<Authentication />);
  |                                     ^

error: Unexpected token `)`. Expected this, import, async, function, [ for array literal, { for object literal, @ for decorator, function, class, null, true, false, number, bigint, string, regexp, ` for template literal, (, or an identifier
 
  |
7 |   const $ = render(<Authentication />);
  |                                      ^



Caused by:
    0: failed to process js file
    1: Syntax Error
    at Compiler.transformSync
```

How can we create that command so that it runs with SWC?

Comment: I also have hundreds of tests file with `.js` extension, all with JSX (testing React code) and am looking for a way for SWC to treat them as `jsx`...

Comment: I've [opened a ticket/question on Github](https://github.com/swc-project/swc/issues/6834) regarding `.js` extension

Comment: Same issue with `vite-plugin-react-swc`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some experimentation I found out that it works if you `import React from 'react';` in every file (both the component as well as the test) and change the file extensions to `.jsx` as described [in the docs](https://github.com/Brooooooklyn/swc-node/tree/master/packages/register#compileroptionsjsx).

However, this is unsatisfying, as we'd like to use [React 17's JSX transform feature](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html) to avoid having to import React in every file. Additionally, we'd like to keep all file endings `.js`.

We tried [setting `.swcrc`](https://swc.rs/docs/configuration/compilation#jsctransformreactruntime) without any luck so far.

I'm posting this answer here in case no way to configure `.swcrc` can be found.

Comment: Did you manage to find a way to do this without having to import?

Comment: @Charklewis yes, see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70899604/swc-with-javascript-how-to-handle-css-imports-and-how-to-absolute-imports?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4):

I'll assume your question is only about jest and not about the webpack setup for swc.

I've never used swc myself in jest so this is just a shot in the dark, but I found a package for jest called `@swc-node/jest` which allows you to use a transformer like:

```
module.exports = {
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(t|j)sx?$': ['@swc-node/jest'],
  },
}
```

Which should allow you to transpile all `[jt]sx?` imports.

There's also a different one called `@swc/jest` which seems to do the same thing.

I'd start with trying those.

Your issue is that jest isn't able to parse your code, for example if you were using typescript you'd need something like `ts-jest` in order to parse your TS for you, I think in this case you need a `swc/jest` transpiler which should first compile your code and output it to memory, then funnel it to jest to run it.

The alternative is that you could compile the tests before hand using swc, then run jest on the compiled files as a separate step.  At least with TS you can do that, first compile everything using `tsc` and then run jest on the `.js` output.  I'm sure swc should work the same.

As to why the `@swc-node/register` package you're using isn't working, I have no idea.

Comment: Hi Matriarx  Thank you for your help! Unfortunately, I'm using RITEway instead of Jest. So while I'm sure what you're saying helps with Jest, I'm looking for ways to make it work with RITEway.

Comment: Ah alright.  Even if you are using something else the concept stays the same, you'll need something to transpile your code to javascript before you can use it.  If you can't find a package that exists for the one you're using like ````swc/jest````, then I guess the only thing I can think of is for you to run ````swc````, compile your code, then run your tests as a second step.