# SWC won't compile jsx content for ".js" files extension

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, babeljs, mocha.js, swc-compiler

### tl;dr

How to make [SWC](https://swc.rs/) compile **`.js`** (not `.jsx`) files which contains *React jsx* for **`mocha`** tests?

---

I'm setting up *Mocha + SWC* (replacing a current *Mocha + Babel* setup), and am facing an issue where SWC won't compile `jsx` content inside `.js` files. It will only do so for `.jsx` files.

I've prepared a minimal [Github repo](https://github.com/yairEO/swc-js-extension-fails-with-jsx-content) showcasing the issue.

I've tried getting help from the SWC GitHub repo, but the help I got was unhelpful and my bug report has been closed, so I guess it won't get much attention now.

### `.swcrc`

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/swcrc",
  "jsc": {
    "parser": {
      "syntax": "ecmascript",
      "jsx": true,
      "dynamicImport": false,
      "privateMethod": true,
      "functionBind": false,
      "exportDefaultFrom": true,
      "exportNamespaceFrom": false,
      "decorators": true,
      "decoratorsBeforeExport": true,
      "topLevelAwait": false,
      "importMeta": false
    },
    "transform": {
      "legacyDecorator": true,
      "react": {
        "pragma": "React.createElement",
        "pragmaFrag": "React.Fragment",
        "throwIfNamespace": true,
        "development": false,
        "useBuiltins": false
      },
      "optimizer": {
        "globals": {
          "vars": {
            "__DEBUG__": "true"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "target": "es5",
    "loose": false,
    "externalHelpers": false,
    // Requires v1.2.50 or upper and requires target to be es2016 or upper.
    "keepClassNames": false
  },
  "module": {
    "type": "commonjs"
  },
  "minify": false
}
```

### `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "swc-js-extension-fails-with-jsx-content",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "SWC not parsing jsx in js files",
  "author": {
    "name": "Yair Even-Or",
    "email": "vsync.design@gmail.com"
  },
  "private": false,
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.17.8",
    "@swc-node/register": "1.5.5",
    "@swc/cli": "0.1.59",
    "@swc/core": "1.3.27",
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "0.8.0",
    "jsdom": "^21.0.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "7.19.3",
    "@babel/core": "7.20.2",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "7.19.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.12.12",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind": "7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "7.12.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7.19.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.18.6",
    "@babel/register": "7.18.9",
    "chai": "4.3.7",
    "enzyme": "3.11.0",
    "mocha": "9.2.2"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "modern": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version"
    ],
    "ssr": [
      "node 14"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha \"src/**/*.test.js\""
  }
}
```

### `jsconfig`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  }
}
```

##### With `Babel` - `.js` files extensions works:

`.mocharc.json` - `"require": ["@babel/register", "setup.js"],`

[image]

##### With `SWC` - does not compile `.js`-extension mocha tests (with `jsx` syntax)

`.mocharc.json` - `"require": ["@swc-node/register", "setup.js"],`

[image]

Comment: Related to [Migrating from Babel to SWC with React](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69956543/104380)